# Facebook permission "birthday" giving me the wrong age

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am trying to pull the birthday to get the age for a user that logs in on my page with Facebook.  I keep trying to log in with my profile, but it is giving me the wrong age.  Below is the code I have in process_facebook.php (I have a database with a field called "age" that takes an int):

```
function getAge($birthday) {
        $dt = strtotime($birthday);
        // convert the birthday to a standard format (UNIX epoch)
        $a = gmdate('Y') - gmdate('Y',$dt);
        // find the difference of years
        $a = (int)$a;
        return $a; // return the age.
    }
```

Within the typical process_facebook.php framework, I have this:

```
$birthday = $me['birthday'];


$age = getAge($birthday);
```

I know my birthday is January 4, 1987 on Facebook (should be pulled as a string "01/04/1987" in $birthday).  But when the field in my database is populated, it has the number 43.

I have tried running the code separately feeding it "01/04/1987" as $birthday, and it spits out 26 fine.

I am not sure what is happening (could Facebook be passing me an incorrect birthday?)  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: it's been 43 years since 1970... which means strtotime() is failing and returning a 0, aka Jan 1,1970, so your 43 is actually a "proper" age. e.g. check what dramabook is REALLY returning and why strtotime is choking on it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I see this variable?  It is in process_facebook.php;  if I print the variable, where does it appear?  or how do I view it in the browser console, etc...

Comment: stick a `var_dump($birthday); die()` into your getAge() function so the script'll spit out what facebook sent over, and then abort.

Comment: Don't forget: The `user.birthday` field must be populated by the user. It can be empty, and may contain only a day and month without a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) if you have really granted your application `user_birthday` permission. Select your app in the dropdown in top right corner and fill textbox with this

```
me?fields=birthday
```

If there is no `birthday` field in the output, you can click <kbd>Get Access Token</kbd> to see what permissions you have granted your app.

I think that you have not granted `user_birthday` permission you your app on authing and `$me['birthday']` is empty. And that's why the calculated age is 43 - years passed since 1970, as [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) pointed in his comment. To check that simply use `var_dump($me['birthday'])`.

And be sure to check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779722/facebook-permission-birthday-giving-me-the-wrong-age/14779905#comment20695361_14779722).

Comment: This was the issue.  Thank you very much for this suggestion.  Good man.